# How to control how many tasks to run per executor in PySpark

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Spark to run a C++ binary that uses a lot of memory.

I am running it like this:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: subprocess.check_call(["./high_memory_usage_executable"]))
```

I have been getting `-9` return code which means that the OS is killing the executable due to out of memory.

I have set:

`spark.mesos.executor.memoryOverhead=20480`
The executable should need around 10g (10240) of memory. So the memoryOverhead setting is very generous.

Question:

1. How do I profile the memory usage and the executable and debug why it is failing.
2. I worry that there are multiple `./high_memory_usage_executable` running per executor. How can I force to have only one executor run each `high_memory_usage_executable`